# Django - libssl.1.1.dylib library not loading error - Why is this occuring?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, openssl

I am trying to migrate my changes in my existing Django project to mysql database using command `python3 manage.py migrate`. I transferred to a new MacBook with Catalina OS and installed everything from scatch. When I try to run the command I keep on getting this error trace stack:

The main cause of this error is this line: `Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/rest_api/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/vincegonzales/Documents/Anteriore/Project Apps/bonggakaday_api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: `Did you install mysqlclient?`, did you?

Comment: Yes, it's already installed, but it still throws that error.

Comment: The main cause of this error is because of this line in the stack trace: Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib